# Stop the android activity spinner manually

Tags: android-listview, android-asynctask

My `ListFragment` fetches data from a REST service using an AsyncTask.
The `onPostExecute()` block returns a success/fail status back to my fragment rather than the result.
In my fragment use this status to show my `ListView` (in case of success) or pop up a toast(in case of failure).

As soon as the `AsyncTask` is executed, an activity circle is shown in the middle of the screen which gets replaced by the `ListView` once the data is available.
In case the data is not available, the toast message does pop up, but the activity circle does not get removed.
I am not declaring anywhere in the code when to start the activity spinner.

How can I stop the activity circle in case of failure?

Here is the code block of the `AsyncTask`:

```
    class invokeServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ServiceResult> {
          @Override
          // method to be run in BG thread
          // pass the mashup parameters to the BG thread
          protected ServiceResult doInBackground(String... id) {
                 return invokeMashupService(id);
          }

          @Override
          // called on UI thread when the worker is done
          protected void onPostExecute(ServiceResult result) {
                 _delegate.mashupReturned(result);
          }
   }
```

If result is returned as SERVICE_FAILURE, I am displaying a toast as seen in the code block below which is executed in the UI after `AsyncTask` is completed.

```
    public void mashupReturned(ServiceResult result) {

          // check for getActivity to counter the case when user presses the back
          // button quickly and the app context is no longer valid.
          if (getActivity() != null) {
                 if (result == ServiceResult.SERVICE_SUCCESS) {
                       // Fetch the array of GroupListItems and create a
                       // GroupListAdapter using it
                       GroupListItem[] list_data = _dataModel.getData();
                       GroupListAdapter adapter = new GroupListAdapter(getActivity(),
                                     R.layout.list_row, list_data);
                       setListAdapter(adapter);
                 } else {
                       // TODO: stop the activity spinner
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                     "Problem invoking service: " + result,
                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
          } else {
                 Log.i("test", "Activity is null");
          }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I can help you with that abstract a piece of code.

The only possible reason I can think of here is that the method invokeMashupService(id) is invoking a ProgressBar or spinner to start animating, and when your ListView's constructor or some other method in it is invoking the call to either stop the animation of the spinner, or to set its visibility to View.INVISIBLE or View.GONE.

Try looking for any ProgressBar or spinner in the xml file of the layout used by this file, and in the failure block of your method mashupReturned, set its visibility to View.GONE if the spinner is no longer reqd, or View.INVISIBLE if the spinner might be required later.

Hope this helps

Anuj

Comment: as i mentioned...i am not setting a spinner anywhere in my xml or anywhere else. I believe it is the spinner that comes between loading of activities. In that case the solution would be to load any kind of activity that shows a relevant failure message

Comment: One thing that I can assure you is that Android SDK does not add any spinner(s) on its own, neither between loading activities nor anywhere else for that matter. I think there's some part of some code related to the method invokeMashupService which is invoking the spinner. It might be a view added by a library used in this method, or a class used/inherited by it might be adding the spinner.

Also, it wouldn't stop appearing unless some code-snippet in GroupListAdapter or GroupListItem is hiding it or stopping its animation.

All the best with this. Please update whenever you find a solution.

Comment: Android does add a spinner between activities/fragments if you do not provide any UI element to the activity/fragment for some time. SOLUTION : Add any UI element to the activity when handling the Failure case and the spinner will stop once the Fail block gets executed. In my case I added a listView header and an empty list and using the listView header I can show any relevant message to the user.

Comment: Somehow forgot about this. You can try this: If you're using a ListFragment you can call setListShown(false) to display a loading progress indicator until you call setListShown(true). You can call these in the fragment's Loader callback methods to show the indicator while the list is loading.
So I guess in your case, you can call setListShown(true) at the place where you're showing the toast, as I believe that that property's set to false by default. This might be more useful as it looks less expensive. Please note that this might not work with custom ListViews, but is still worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED..
I was not setting any UI element in the Failure state because of which the activity spinner was persisting.
I removed the Toast statement and added a Header row along with an empty ListView. This stops the spinner and shows me the message I want in the header.